# destroy() not destroying on repeats

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

My code creates a `Tk` window with 3 entry boxes and 3 buttons. When a button is clicked the adjacent entry box and the button itself should disappear. I want to use destroy because I don't use it again. The problem is that it works the first time on any of the button/entry components but when I click any of the other buttons after one has destroyed, none of the others will destroy.

```
class BlackjackTable:
    def __init__(self,numPlayers):
        self.numPlayers=numPlayers
        self.tableWindow=Tk()
        self.bettedE=False
        self.bettedS=False
        self.bettedW=False
        self.betCount=0
        self.suitWindow()
    def suitWindow(self):
        self.tableWindow.title("Blackjack Table")
        self.tableWindow.config(bg="dark green")
        if int(self.betCount)!=int(self.numPlayers) and (not self.bettedE):
            self.EHandEntry=Entry(self.tableWindow,fg="white",bg="dark green",width=10)
            self.EHandEntry.grid(row=5,column=9)

            self.EHandSubmit=Button(self.tableWindow,text="Bet",fg="white",padx=15,pady=5,command=self.betE,bg="dark green",activebackground="dark green",activeforeground="white")
            self.EHandSubmit.grid(row=5,column=10)
        if self.numPlayers>=2:
            if (self.betCount!=self.numPlayers) and (not self.bettedS):
                self.SHandEntry=Entry(self.tableWindow,fg="white",bg="dark green",width=10)
                self.SHandEntry.grid(row=8,column=6)

                self.SHandSubmit=Button(self.tableWindow,text="Bet",fg="white",padx=15,pady=5,command=self.betST,bg="dark green",activebackground="dark green",activeforeground="white")
                self.SHandSubmit.grid(row=8,column=7)
        if self.numPlayers==3:
            if (self.betCount!=self.numPlayers) and (not self.bettedW):
                self.WHandEntry=Entry(self.tableWindow,fg="white",bg="dark green",width=10)
                self.WHandEntry.grid(row=5,column=3)

                self.WHandSubmit=Button(self.tableWindow,text="Bet",fg="white",padx=15,pady=5,command=self.betW,bg="dark green",activebackground="dark green",activeforeground="white")
                self.WHandSubmit.grid(row=5,column=4)
    def betE(self):
        print("betE")
        self.bettedE=True
        self.EHandSubmit.destroy()
        self.EHandEntry.destroy()
        self.suitWindow()
        self.betCount+=1
    def betST(self):
        print("betST")
        self.bettedS=True
        self.SHandSubmit.destroy()
        self.SHandEntry.destroy()
        self.suitWindow()
        self.betCount+=1
    def betW(self):
        print("betW")
        self.bettedW=True
        self.WHandSubmit.destroy()
        self.WHandEntry.destroy()
        self.suitWindow()
        self.betCount+=1
gui=BlackjackTable(3)
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You faced that problem because inside these methods: `betE()`, `betST()` and `betW()` you call uselessly `suitWindow()` which redraws the componenents based on complicated `if` conditions.

The solution is that you start by drawing your widgets using `suitWindow()` by getting rid of all the `if` conditions based on the values and states of `self.numPlayers`,        `self.bettedE`, `self.bettedS`,        `self.bettedW` and  `self.betCount` flags:

```
def suitWindow(self):
        self.tableWindow.title("Blackjack Table")
        self.tableWindow.config(bg="dark green")

        self.EHandEntry=Entry(self.tableWindow,fg="white",bg="dark green",width=10)
        self.EHandEntry.grid(row=5,column=9)

        self.EHandSubmit=Button(self.tableWindow,text="Bet",fg="white",padx=15,pady=5,command=self.betE,bg="dark green",activebackground="dark green",activeforeground="white")
        self.EHandSubmit.grid(row=5,column=10)


        self.SHandEntry=Entry(self.tableWindow,fg="white",bg="dark green",width=10)
        self.SHandEntry.grid(row=8,column=6)

        self.SHandSubmit=Button(self.tableWindow,text="Bet",fg="white",padx=15,pady=5,command=self.betST,bg="dark green",activebackground="dark green",activeforeground="white")
        self.SHandSubmit.grid(row=8,column=7)
        self.WHandEntry=Entry(self.tableWindow,fg="white",bg="dark green",width=10)
        self.WHandEntry.grid(row=5,column=3)

        self.WHandSubmit=Button(self.tableWindow,text="Bet",fg="white",padx=15,pady=5,command=self.betW,bg="dark green",activebackground="dark green",activeforeground="white")
        self.WHandSubmit.grid(row=5,column=4)
```

Once these widgets are drawn, just use [`destroy()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.destroy-method) as you did and forget about suitWindow() method. Thus the three remaining methods become:

```
    def betE(self):
        print("betE")
        self.bettedE=True
        self.EHandSubmit.destroy()
        self.EHandEntry.destroy()

    def betST(self):
        print("betST")
        self.bettedS=True
        self.SHandSubmit.destroy()
        self.SHandEntry.destroy()

    def betW(self):
        print("betW")
        self.bettedW=True
        self.WHandSubmit.destroy()
        self.WHandEntry.destroy()
```

## Full program

Your program becomes *less complicated* as you code less:

```
'''
Created on Apr 23, 2016

@author: billal begueradj
'''
from tkinter import *
class BlackjackTable:
    def __init__(self,numPlayers):
        self.numPlayers=numPlayers
        self.tableWindow=Tk()
        self.bettedE=False
        self.bettedS=False
        self.bettedW=False
        self.suitWindow()
    def suitWindow(self):
        self.tableWindow.title("Blackjack Table")
        self.tableWindow.config(bg="dark green")

        self.EHandEntry=Entry(self.tableWindow,fg="white",bg="dark green",width=10)
        self.EHandEntry.grid(row=5,column=9)

        self.EHandSubmit=Button(self.tableWindow,text="Bet",fg="white",padx=15,pady=5,command=self.betE,bg="dark green",activebackground="dark green",activeforeground="white")
        self.EHandSubmit.grid(row=5,column=10)


        self.SHandEntry=Entry(self.tableWindow,fg="white",bg="dark green",width=10)
        self.SHandEntry.grid(row=8,column=6)

        self.SHandSubmit=Button(self.tableWindow,text="Bet",fg="white",padx=15,pady=5,command=self.betST,bg="dark green",activebackground="dark green",activeforeground="white")
        self.SHandSubmit.grid(row=8,column=7)
        self.WHandEntry=Entry(self.tableWindow,fg="white",bg="dark green",width=10)
        self.WHandEntry.grid(row=5,column=3)

        self.WHandSubmit=Button(self.tableWindow,text="Bet",fg="white",padx=15,pady=5,command=self.betW,bg="dark green",activebackground="dark green",activeforeground="white")
        self.WHandSubmit.grid(row=5,column=4)
    def betE(self):
        print("betE")
        self.bettedE=True
        self.EHandSubmit.destroy()
        self.EHandEntry.destroy()

    def betST(self):
        print("betST")
        self.bettedS=True
        self.SHandSubmit.destroy()
        self.SHandEntry.destroy()

    def betW(self):
        print("betW")
        self.bettedW=True
        self.WHandSubmit.destroy()
        self.WHandEntry.destroy()

gui=BlackjackTable(3)
mainloop()
```